# I cannot locate where mvc4 store its database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am very new to MVC4 and try to learn everything by doing a simple project. I created a model and a control succesfully. But I couldnt understand where it stores its database.

I can do insert,delete,update records on webpage created by ASP.NET, but I cannot locate where that database is. I checked the web.config but there is no connection string. how can I find out where the system stores its data?

I have sql-server installed on my computer but I checked it and it is not stored there

Comment: Yes, there's a connectionString. Probably, you're searching in the wrong web.config file (there's more than one).

Comment: You should have a connection string in the web.config.

Comment: Try looking in /App_Data/

Comment: Which `Web.config`? There are several web.configs in typical MVC4 project. Make sure you check in the root Web.config.

Comment: App_Data is empty. I checked the main web.config and the one under views/ but I cannot seen the connection string

Comment: If you are using VS 2012, there's a default connstring in the Global.asax file.

Comment: Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

Comment: I found the database under app_data but it seems empty when u look from visual studio. I went to the same folder with explorer and I saw that it is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC4 stores the database in an `mdf` file located in your `App_Data` folder. The connection string is available in the top-level `web.config`.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication6-20130610160316;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication6-20130610160316.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            // Use LocalDB for Entity Framework by default
            Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```